# Xamarin layout how to place a label in bottom left corner and bottom right corner of screen

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app I'm trying to place two labels on my mobile interface, one in the bottom left corner, one in the bottom right.

Here is my current attempt. It is a grid layout with one row and two columns, with a label in each cell, the left one with `HorizontalTextAlightment="Start"` and the right one with `HorizontalTextAlightment="End"`

```
    ...other unrelated controls...
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" Padding="15" VerticalOptions="End" >
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Text="{Binding DeviceId}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Version}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
      </Grid>


    </StackLayout>

  </StackLayout>
```

This produces this unwanted result: (the v1.0-1 should be aligned to the right)

[image: current]

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: Try to use HorizontalOptions  as StartAndExpand for first label & EndAndExpand for second label rather than HorizontalTextAlignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you wrapping the view in a `StackLayout`? A `Stacklayout` will allocate the minimum amount of space required. Which is why you are seeing the behavior you have shown in Screenshot 1.

If you just have:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Text="{Binding DeviceId}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Version}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
  </Grid>
```

You will see the desired behavior.

You could also try using `HorizontalOptions` on the `Label` instead of `HorizontalTextAlignment`

---

If you really need to use a `StackLayout` you could try setting the `HorizontalOptions` of the `StackLayout` to `FillAndExpand`. which states:

> **FillAndExpand** – places the view so that it has no padding and takes up
>   as much space as the layout will give it.

**ref:** https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout/#Sizing

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Label Text="{Binding DeviceId}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
  <Label Text="{Binding Version}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "*" for width only makes the column as big as it needs to be in order to fit its contents.  Instead, try making each column 50% of the total width.

```
      <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
```

Comment: I thought the `"#*"` was only interpreted as a ratio compared to the other sibling rows (or columns)